# Issues opening laptop camera with opencv in python on a Mac (macOS Catalina 10.15)

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I'd like to open my laptop's camera via a python script using on opencv. The script works on Linux but is causing issues on Mac. Here is the part that is causing issues:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)

if not cap.isOpened():
  raise ConnectionError("Could not open video device")
```

As the ConnectionError is raised I assume the `cv2.VideoCapture(-1)` part is not working but I don't understand why that is the case. What could be different to running the script in a Linux environment? It also seams to be working on other macOS versions...

---

**Edit:**
That part of the error message might be helpful:

> [ERROR:0] global [...] open VIDEOIO(AVFOUNDATION): raised unknown C++
> exception!

I found some other Mac users experiencing the issue but could not find a solution that works for me

Answer (score 0):

I know next to nothing about OpenCV, but since I happened to be relaxing on the couch with a Catalina laptop, I decided to have a go. This works for me:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
res, frame = cap.read()
```

This seems consistent with the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aabce0d83aa0da9af802455e8cf5fd181) stating that index zero is the default device.

When I ran it from Terminal.app, I had to click ok in a dialog to grant Terminal access to the camera. (I suppose this means that *any* app run from the Terminal gets camera access, which may not be what you want.)

Comment: I really appreciate that you spend your couch time on that issue :). however I already tried `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` and it does not work for me. I added a part of the error message, which might be useful to my question

Comment: It was that or emptying the dishwasher. :) Sorry it didn't work.